# Trying to make case expression in WHERE clause (one value equals multiple)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to be able to make a case expression in the `WHERE` clause that will use a variable to make a determination as to which criteria to apply:

```
declare @Classification VARCHAR(20)
set @Classification = 'Leaseup/Stabilized' 

select *
from attributes a
where 
    if @Classification = 'Leaseup/Stabilized' then a.subgroup8 in ('Lease-up Communities', 'Stabilized 
        Communities')
    if @Classification = 'Product Type' then a.subgroup6 in ('Freestanding AL/ALZ', 'Rental Continuums')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use regular logic:

```
select a.*
from attributes a
where (@Classification = 'Leaseup/Stabilized' and a.subgroup8 in ('Lease-up Communities', 'Stabilized Communities'
      ) OR
      (@Classification = 'Product Type' and a.subgroup6 in ('Freestanding AL/ALZ', 'Rental Continuums')
      )
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I'm still learning. This worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `Case` in where

```
      declare @Classification 
       VARCHAR(20)
        set @Classification = 
       'Leaseup/Stabilized' 

   select *
     from attributes a
     where 
   1=  max (Case when @Classification = 
 'Leaseup/Stabilized' and a.subgroup8 in 
   ('Lease-up Communities', 'Stabilized 
    Communities') then 1 end) or
  1=   max (Case when @Classification = 
    'Product Type' and a.subgroup6 in 
    ('Freestanding AL/ALZ', 'Rental 
      Continuums') then 1 end)
```